# how can I continue checking if my Swift app has an internet connection?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm writing a simple app that fetches data from webservice and displays it to the user. I have a `UIViewController` with a label and I have a code as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.myLabel.text = ""
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://mywebservice.com/fetchData")
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .Success:
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print("JSON: \(json)")
                    let numberOfUsers = json["usersNo"]
                    self.myLabel.text = "We found \(numberOfUsers) users in database"

                }

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("SWITCH ERROR")
                print(error)
            }

    }    
}
```

When user enters this panel he sees the activity indicator running until data is fetched - and when it happens the activity indicator disappears and `myLabel` is filled with data. That works fine, but when user doesn't have for a short while the internet connection and enters the panel, fetch request won't return any data and the indicator will keep moving around. In that case it would be nice to keep checking if the internet connection is there and whether it's possible to fetch the data.

How can I keep checking if the internet connection is active and - if it is - hide my activity indicator and display fetched data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know whether the request has succeeded or failed until it's over and *has* succeeded or failed. When it has, the network interaction is over. Move the `stopAnimating:` call so that it happens regardless of success or failure:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://mywebservice.com/fetchData")
    .responseJSON { response in
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        switch response.result { // and so on
```

If you want to try try try again in case of failure, simply abstract your request into its own function that calls itself recursively in case of failure:

```
func doRequest() {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://mywebservice.com/fetchData")
        .responseJSON { response in
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                // whatever
            case .Failure(let error):
                doRequest() // <-- try again
            }
    }    
}
```

Now call that function from within your `viewWillAppear`. I don't think that's a very good strategy — in fact, I would warn you against doing — but if that's what you want to do, go right ahead.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not exactly the behavior of the app that I expect... I want to show the indicator for as long as user is offline and as soon as he retrieves the internet connection, then I want to hide the indicator and display freshly fetched data...

Comment: Internet is trial and error. You know whether you have a connection by trying to connect and either succeeding or failing. There isn't some magic meta-testing you can do.

Comment: Of course :) but when I fail once during first connection I want to repeat such process (trying to connect) until I finally have a connection - and in the meantime I want to show the indicator view. And this is the part that I don't know how to do and the reason why I asked this question :)

Comment: Then implement your `.Failure` case to try again. This isn't going to happen magically all by itself.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to do it. But don't. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

`Alamofire` has the `Reachablity` implemented, check https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#network-reachability.

There is a important note:

- Do NOT use Reachability to determine if a network request should be sent.

  - You should ALWAYS send it.

In your case, keeping the `Activity Indicator` spinning whiling there is network problem isn't a good practice or `User Experience`.

Some advice:

1. When the request failed, figure out what is the error first.  If it's network problem, let EndUser know there is network problem and check the network settings.
2. Save last request, in case you want to retry if the network restored.